# Makefile missing separator error in spite of using the correct indentation

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, makefile

Although I have done some research about the error and understood that it has something to do with indentation. I still cannot figure out what is wrong with my Makefile which causes terminal to give error: `Makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.`
while running `make clean` command. 
My Makefile has the content bellow:

```
obj-m := S3538332Device.o
KERNEL_DIR /usr/src/linux-headers-$(shell uname -r)
all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order *~
```

I tried and ran  `cat -e -t -v {Makefile}` to make sure that the tabs are at the right places:

```
obj-m := S3538332Device.o$
KERNEL_DIR /usr/src/linux-headers-$(shell uname -r)$
all:$
^I$(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules$
clean:$
^Irm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order *~$
```

I am very new to makefile and c programming in general and I can't manage to find anything wrong with my code. Can anyone help me find out what the problem is that causes the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an assignment operator, it should be

```
KERNEL_DIR = /usr/src/linux-headers-$(shell uname -r)
```

or commonly KERNEL_DIR is usually only set if it's not already set:

```
KERNEL_DIR ?= /usr/src/linux-headers-$(shell uname -r)
```